# Vue not applying style class

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, webpack

I have single-file components that are built with the following Webpack configuration:

```
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 8192
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[local]_[hash:base64:8]'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ]
```

I use the `<style scoped>` tag to style my components. This works with tag selectors (e.g. `nav`), but class selectors (e.g. `.content`) result in no styling. The DOM contains the relevant classes, but the generated `dist/main.js` file only contains a `content_xgKyi9qt[data-v-ab83c772]` selector, which is not applied, as the component only has the raw `content` class.

Comment: share gitrepo link to your code

Comment: Share image of console where we can see HTML element and styles together.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `vue-style-loader` options that I used are causing the name mangling. I have decided to switch from `<style scoped>` to `<style module>` and use the `<div :class="$style.content">` syntax instead.

This causes the class of the element to correspond to the mangled name and provides a level of isolation for styling.